# Dblookup not working

Tags: web, lotus-domino, lotus

```
temp:=@DbLookup("Notes":"NoCache";"ARRoW/SSS":"sss/sssProj.nsf";"(Lookup for Community)";"State of Maine";2);

temp1:=@DbLookup("Notes":"NoCache";"ARRoW/SSS":"sss/sssProj.nsf";"(Lookup for Community)";"State of Maine";3);

temp2:=@DbLookup("Notes":"NoCache";"ARRoW/SSS":"sss/sssProj.nsf";"(Lookup for Community POC)";"State of Maine";4);

@If(@IsError(temp)|@IsError(temp1)|@IsError(temp2);"Error";temp + " " + temp1 + " " + temp2)
```

Hi this works on Lotus Notes Client but doesn't work on web Any help is welcome thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work on web"? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: According to last line it returns "Error" It Is supposed to return a name with title. 

@If(@IsError(temp)|@IsError(temp1)|@IsError(temp2);"Error";temp + " " + temp1 + " " + temp2)

Answer (score 2):

There are typically three types of root causes for something like this.

One type of problem is server trust. This only applies if there are two servers involved. I.e., the web server is ServerX/SSS and the code is trying to access ARRoW/SSS. You need to review ARRoW/SSS's server document and check whether "ServerX/SSS" is listed in the field for "Trusted servers". (Also note that if this is a really, really old version of Domino - before version 6 if I recall correctly - then the trusted servers feature is not there and you cannot make cross-server calls to @DbLookup in web code.)

The second type of problem is that the server where the code is running can not resolve the name of the server where the database lives. The code is accessing server ARRoW/SSS, but you haven't said whether ARRoW/SSS is the actual web server, so let's look at both cases.

Assuming that it is all happening on one server, there can still be a name resolution problem because of the way the formula is coded. Try specifying "":"sss/sssProj.nsf" instead of "ARRoW/SSS":"sss/sssProj.nsf". If that fixes your problem, great! But it means that you still have a problem either in your server document or with the DNS configuration on your Domino server and you should address that. You should probably continue with the troubleshooting that I give in the next paragraph. Just bear in mind that everything I say there is true even if ServerX/SSS is really the same as Arrow/SSS.

If the code is running on web server ServerX/SSS, then you need to make sure that ServerX can connect to ARRoW/SSS. The easiest way to do this is to bring up the console for ServerX and enter the command 'trace ARRoW/SSS'. If it fails, check the server documents and/or connection documents for correct IP addresses or host names, and open a command window on the server and try a ping using the exact information in the server documents. If it fails, you have a networking issue. One of the underlying causes I've seen for a problem like this is that there is no connection document (because the servers are in the same named network, but neither the IP address nor the fully-qualified host name is entered in the networks table in the server document, so Domino just asks DNS to resolve the common name 'ARRow' - but the DNS configuration on the web server does not include a default search path so the name is not resolved. But you need to check everything until you can get a 'trace' command to succeed.

The third type of problem is Access Control. This is a broad category that comes down to the fact that the identity that the code is running under either does not have access to the server ARRoW/SSS, the database sss/sssProj.nsf, the view (Lookup for Community)" or the document(s) with the key "State of Maine". There are a lot of things to check. If the code is running in a field formula, the identity is that of the user, and if the same user does not get the error through the web client then you need to look at the database properties for sss/sssProj.nsf and check the maximum web access level. If the code is running as an agent, you need to check the agent properties to determine what identity the agent is running under, and then review everything: the security settings in the server document, the database ACL, restrictions on the view, and reader names fields in the documents.

Comment: Thanks very much it is very flaky When I added Computed text As @Text(DBLookup....) it brought the error server not found then it also putting server as @Subset(@DBName;1) brought the value in view source, that was expected. Again when I put the formula on subform it stopped working. Thanks very much for your advise, I will check all those parameters. Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi Richard: It worked finally. The reason it was not giving correct value was very simple and not known or seen before. there was a value stored in that shared field and that field did not recomputed even though it was a computed field. So I had to clear the field value by making it @Unavailable. And then let the correct formula recomputed. So it didn't matter if that field was on the sub form. The things that you have mentioned are great as I was not aware of it as I am not very much on the admin side. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem.